# How can I trace a variable at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, trace

How can I track a variable's values as they change, at runtime, in C#? I'm interested in the same functionality that the debugger provides when I'm tracing a variable through execution steps, only that I need to call upon it from my code. Some sort of key-value observing, but for all kinds of variables(local, class, static, etc), not only properties. So, basically, receive a notification when a variable's value changes.

Comment: Why is the debugger not an option? That's exactly what it is for.

Comment: @0xA3 Because I need to access those values from within my application, at runtime, only when they change.

Comment: How about writing the changes values of the variable to a simple log file.

Comment: @Shivam that's a consequence of a variable tracking, not the cause 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working from the assumption that the debugger can track variable changes.  It can't.

It is possible with unmanaged code, the processor has dedicated debug registers that allow setting data breakpoints.  Up to three are provided.  It generates a hardware interrupt when it sees a particular memory location getting written.  This otherwise very useful feature isn't available in managed code however.  The garbage collector is completely incompatible with it, it moves objects around, giving them another address.

The managed debugger does support a "when hit" condition on a breakpoint, allowing you to dump info to the output window.  That however requires a breakpoint, it cannot be triggered by a change in variable value.  It also *really* slows down code execution since the debugger actually enters a break state before executing the condition.

The obvious place to put such a breakpoint is in a property setter.  Which is what you'll need to implement this feature in code.  You can do anything you want in that setter, using the Trace class for example.

Comment: ⁺¹ for the answer, I however a bit disagree with a point of a big slowing down of a simple conditional breakpoint. Since C# being converted to a bytecode, most appropriate way for a debugger is just create and insert a bytecode that does print a value in the place of the value. I don't see a reason why couldn't it be done just this way — and hence another implementation of a debugger breakpoint I'd call a performance bug.

Comment: No, C# is converted to machine code, IL is just an intermediary step.  Use Debug > Windows > Disassembly to see it.  Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what Marc said, if you want to do this for lots of properties and methods you might want to check out aspect oriented programming techniques, and libraries such as PostSharp.

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp

Answer (score 1):

The managed debugger uses the `ICorDebug` COM API for pretty much everything.  The part that you're interested is `ICorDebugValue` and its descendants.  Note that a LOT of the debugging API requires that the process be not running (ie, have encountered a breakpoint) in order for the various inspections to happen.   A high level overview of `ICorDebug` is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422175204/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/01/04/icordebug-overview.aspx).  The documentation on it is kinda sparse, but some Googling may help.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way you could do that *without* the debugger would be: don't use a variable, but use a property, and (perhaps conditionally) add trace to the setter:

```
private int myValue;
public int MyValue {
    get {return myValue;}
    set {
        SomeTraceMethod(myValue, value, ...);
        myValue = value;
    }
}
```

Obviously this cannot then be used for *arbitrary* fields/variables.

Comment: How does the debugger do it for arbitrary variables? Isn't there a debugging library that could help me achieve the same level of tracking?

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned a mechanism like that makes only sense when using properties. In .NET you can then make use of the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

For a sample how to implement it see

> **[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)**

The referenced article talks explicitly about Windows Forms, but you are not bound to that (the interface is actually declared in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace in System.dll). In fact, this interface is widely used for data binding scenarios, e.g. in WPF.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I'm interested in arbitrary variables, not properties. I know about INotifyPropertyChanged, what I don't know is how to trace arbitrary variables, like the debugger does.