# Display simple test string/value

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new in Visual Studio (2015) and C# and am having trouble with something very basic. What I'm trying to do is to simply test a function by displaying some text, that indicates the function this is executed from is called. I'm making a WPF application.

I have experience with javascript, php and Actionscript 3/Flash, and in all these languages it's easy to simply write a line of text, to see whether a function is called or see the value of a variable; with something like `trace()`, `console.write()` etc.

However, after looking for hours to a simple way for do this in C#, I can't find any way to do this without writing whole blocks of code or having this text written to some external file.

To my understanding, `Trace.WriteLine()` writes its content to an external file and needs a whole bunch of additional lines of code to have it displayed somewhere else. Same for `Console.WriteLine()`, because you first have to summon the console to be opened first.

As for now, I'm using `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test")`, but this isn't very convenient in my opinion. I cannot imagine there is no other simple way to trace a simple string or var or something.

Please help this rookie out!

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but when I use this I don't see the string displayed anywhere?

Comment: You will see it in Visual Studio's Output window. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for can be achieved with [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx).

It will display in the Output window of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise there was a pane I had to add to the default GUI of Visual Studio. Strange that it isn't there by default.

Comment: p.s. is there also a way to do this without seeing a whole lot of 'ProjectName.vshost.exe (..)' lines surrounding this?

Comment: You can right click the pane and uncheck everything except `Program Output` to remove those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Console.WriteLine() or Debug.WriteLine(). For the later, if you don't see the output, check this post:[Where does System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write output appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159755/where-does-system-diagnostics-debug-write-output-appear).

For further examples on Debug.WriteLine(), see:[DotNetPerls-Debug](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debug-write).

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned, if you use `Console.WriteLine()` then the console doesn't automatically pop up. This method is too devious for a simple test.

Comment: Nothing makes messages popup except MessageBox.Show() (or a similar coded implementation). However, The managed debugger does support a "when hit" condition on a breakpoint, allowing you to dump info to the output window.  For more on that see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912183/how-can-i-trace-a-variable-at-runtime-in-c